# Etiqueta HR no se visualiza en windows mail

Tags: html

Estoy realizando la maquetación de una serie de correos y en estos momentos ya he conseguido que en la mayoria de gestores de correos se vean bien, el problema en que en windows mail los dos hr que tengos puestos no se visualizan en cambio en outlook si.

```
 <table align="center">
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <hr style="margin-left: -10px; width: 220px; margin-top: 5px; border-top: 1px solid white;"/>    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://foto.png" width="32" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <hr style="width: 250px; margin-top: 5px; display: inline-block; border-top: 1px solid white;"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

¿ A alguien se le ocurre el porque no salen las dos lineas ?

Gracias.

Comment: Primero, están dentro de una tabla. Prueba a cambiar el color del borde (como el fondo también sea blanco poco vas a ver), ponerlas fuera de la tabla a ver si ocurre lo mismo, también a ponerlas sin cierre: `<hr>` (estás usando la sintaxis que viene de XHTML).